# Is there any significance behind Joker's aliases?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker

Joker has many aliases he uses to get away with various purchases and transactions without revealing that he is in-fact the Joker. Some include names like Melvin White, Jack White,  Jack Napier, Joe Kerr, Dr. J Reko, and Oberon Sexton.

A name like Joe Kerr is an obvious homophone for Joker, but is there any significance behind the other names he uses? We know Joker is psychotic so it's possible he's just pulling names out of a hat, but I was wondering if there is any significance as to why he uses these names either in universe or something that the writers have stated for why they picked those names for him to use.

Comment: I kind of like the idea of an alternate universe where Batman and the Joker battle in Hong Kong, and the Joker uses "Ho Haha" is an alias...

Comment: I don't know if there are in-universe justifications, but "Jack Napier" is most likely a reference to Burton's *Batman* film

Comment: @onewho - Dr. J. Reko is another anagram.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Dr. J. Reko

> When Gordon walks into the dental office, the name on the door is "Dr. J. Reko", an anagram of "Joker".

From the DC Animated Universe Wiki entry for "Mad Love", which is the series finale of The New Batman Adventures. It first aired on January 11, 1999. It provides the back story of Harley Quinn, the Joker's girlfriend, and was based on the comic book of the same name. Both the episode and the comic book were written by Paul Dini.

https://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Love

---

#### Melvin White

Appears to some to be the real identity of the Joker according to [Batman Wikia](https://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Melvin_White),

Regardless, Melvin White was linked to the murders of Patrick Harvey and Richard Dent.  How the Joker is linked to Melvin White in all of this is up for speculation.

---

#### Oberon Sexton

[Comic Vine](https://www.comicvine.com/oberon-sexton/4005-69844/) has this to say

> Oberon Sexton was an English best-selling crime author and "amateur" detective. He was killed by the Joker who later usurped his identity.

---

#### Jack Napier

Was the Joker's real name in the 1988 Batman movie starring Michael Keaton and Jack Nicholson.

---

#### Jack White

Jack White is all over several forums with little or no evidence as to where the names came from.  Most sources I found point fingers at the name Jack White being Joker's real name.  This could be a play on <s>the White make-up that Joker wears</s> Joker's white face. (*Most media portrays Joker as having a bleached white face without make-up*)

Comment: Jack Napier was the Joker's real name in the 1988 Batman movie starring Michael Keaton and Jack Nicholson.

Comment: @WadCheber, thank you, I just stole your comment for use in my answer....lol

Comment: No problem.  Having been in the generation that saw the Michael Keaton Batman movie as children, and having fallen in love with Batman as a result, I briefly assumed that Jack Napier was his real name everywhere, and I wouldn't be surprised if many other people my age thought the same thing.

Comment: I didn't watch Batman very often, my dad was into John Wayne and Clint Eastwood, and not so much into Sci Fi.  I like Star Trek though.  I was 3 years old when that Batman movie came out. maybe it is on Netflix....

Comment: I would speculate that the names including the word "White" are referring to his skin color.

Comment: @WadCheber that is what I was thinking too.

Comment: Too bad you didn't say this a couple of weeks ago.  The 1988 Batman movie was in heavy rotation on cable for several weeks, up to about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Minor point:  In the comics, and in every movie except The Dark Knight, Joker's face is permanently bleached white.  No makeup involved.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95716/does-joker-wear-makeup-in-the-comics/95906#95906

Comment: "Jack Napier" also sounds like the word *jackanapes*, meaning "impudent person" - pretty much the same idea as *joker*.

Comment: There's also a "clown" connection in Oberon Sexton.  Sexton's are gravediggers.  Oberon is a character from Shakepseare, and in Shakespeare, gravediggers are often referred to as "clowns".  (I can't remember which issue Batman figures this out in, sadly, but he does).